# Conditional Rendering - Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

This might be very naive question. But I want to conditional render Vue components based on the binary numbers. Like so below. My question is why component renders even not a binary value?

**This renders**

```
<component v-if=1> this is test </component>
```

**This doesn't render**

```
 <component v-if=0> this is test </component>
```

**This renders too. Why?**

```
 <component v-if=111> this is test </component>
```

Comment: i think because: console.log(0==false) //true

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp